# Beaglebone black CAN messages sending problem

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I'm able to receive the CAN messages successfully while the CAN is in ERROR-ACTIVE state.

```
2: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE (berr-counter tx 0 rx 0) restart-ms 0 
      bitrate 500000 sample-point 0.875 
      tq 125 prop-seg 6 phase-seg1 7 phase-seg2 2 sjw 1
      c_can: tseg1 2..16 tseg2 1..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..1024 brp-inc 1
      clock 24000000
      re-started bus-errors arbit-lost error-warn error-pass bus-off
      7          0          0          10         16         7         numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    19321178   2661559  6       0       6       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        0       11      0       0
```

But when I' trying to send data using `cansend 280#22F18C`, it shows BUS-OFF.

```
2: can0: <NO-CARRIER,NOARP,UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 
    can state BUS-OFF (berr-counter tx 248 rx 0) restart-ms 0 
      bitrate 500000 sample-point 0.875 
      tq 125 prop-seg 6 phase-seg1 7 phase-seg2 2 sjw 1
      c_can: tseg1 2..16 tseg2 1..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..1024 brp-inc 1
      clock 24000000
      re-started bus-errors arbit-lost error-warn error-pass bus-off
      7          0          0          11         17         8         numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    20884231   2876864  6       0       6       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        0       11      0       0
```

I'm receiving messages from another node using a transceiver, but unable to send the message.

Comment: Not sure, if you simply forgot in the question or if this could be the problem:  `cansend 280#22F18C` normally should give you an error, as you need to add the interface, e.g. via `cansend can0 280#22F18C`.

Comment: yep typo cansend can0 280#22F12C

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out why this is? We are having a similar issue using SocketCAN on a custom AM335x-based board and can't seem to find the issue.